# Write ASCII to serial port using java

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to write ASCII code 1 to the serial port. But now, I am facing problem with writing it to the serial port. Can I know the way to write ASCII to the serial port.

This is my java code:

```
 String number = "1";
 byte arduinoo[] = number.getBytes();
 for(int i=0; i<arduinoo.length; i++){
     outputStream.write(arduinoo[i]);
     System.out.println(arduinoo[i]);
     outputStream.flush();
 }
```

Can anyone help me with this problem

Comment: You said you have a problem, but never explained *what the problem is*. Are you getting an exception? Wrong output? You'll need to add some more information to your question.

Comment: Well I am writing to the serial port and it shows successful but my serial port not reading my signal. Actually not a problem, just i felt the method I am writing might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to send a byte value of 0x1 to the arduinoo...

but simply trying to send the String won't work so easy... because if you get the bytes from the string you (usually) get the 'ASCII-Code' of each character stored in the byte[]

```
    String strA = "1";
    byte[] dataA = strA.getBytes();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataA.length; i ++){
        int asInt = dataA[i];
        System.out.println("it's not what was expected..."+asInt);
    }

    String strB = "1";
    byte[] dataB = new byte[]{(byte)Integer.parseInt(strB)}; //parsing the String literal into an Integer

    for (int i = 0; i < dataB.length; i ++){
        int asInt = dataB[i];
        System.out.println("this is what was expected..."+asInt);
    }
```

which leads to unwanted/wanted results:

```
it's not what was expected...49
this is what was expected...1
```

so whenever you want to send bytes explixit then create them directly!

```
byte[] data = new byte[]{1,2,3};
```